# why is warning for variable being uninitialized supressed when kernel is compiled with size optimization config enabled?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

trying to optimize kernel boot time, I disabled the `CONFIG_CC_OPTIMIZE_FOR_SIZE` flag in config. This resulted in a lot of `may-be uninitialized` warning (which was treated as error).

Trying to debug that I found that in Makefile:

```
ifdef CONFIG_CC_OPTIMIZE_FOR_SIZE
KBUILD_CFLAGS   += -Os $(call cc-disable-warning,maybe-uninitialized,)
else
KBUILD_CFLAGS   += -O2
endif
```

I dont understand the reson behind disabling the warning for uninitialized variable when kernel is size optimized and not other wise. What is the thought behind this and if i add flag to ignore the uninitialized variables in the later case of "not optimized for size", what issues I can face if any.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very recent kernels (5.1 and later - not yet released at the time of writing - see [commit b303c6df80c9](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=b303c6df80c9f8f13785aa83a0471fca7e38b24d) ("[kbuild: compute false-positive -Wmaybe-uninitialized cases in Kconfig](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=b303c6df80c9f8f13785aa83a0471fca7e38b24d)")) have a separate config option `CONFIG_CC_DISABLE_WARN_MAYBE_UNINITIALIZED` to disable the warning. Those kernels define the option by default for GCC version 4.7 (which introduced the warning) and GCC version 4.8, but the option can be configured manually.

For your kernel and compiler version, it should be safe to modify the Makefile to add `$(call cc-disable-warning,maybe-uninitialized,)` globally. Alternatively, you could consider using GCC 4.9 or later.